# does netstat established mean that someone is ssh'd into my machine

Tags: linux, ssh, logs, netstat

I ran the command `netstat -lat`

and I got this output...

```
...
tcp        0      0 my.machine.ip.add:ssh       116.31.116.48:43270     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 my.machine.ip.add:ssh       my.home.ip.add:55732    ESTABLISHED
...
```

I looked up the IP and it is definitely not one which should have access to my machine. so does `ESTABLISHED` mean that they are trying to connect? (I do see a lot of failed attempts from this address in my auth.log) or does it mean they are connected?

Comment: It means that the tcp connection is established.

Comment: does that say anything about whether they are actually authenticated?

Comment: look at `/var/log/auth.log`

Answer (score 6):

"ESTABLISHED" just means that the connection is established at the TCP layer; it doesn't tell you much of anything about whether they've authenticated. The general sequence is:

1. TCP connection from client (/attacker) to server gets established
2. Client attempts to authenticate
3. If the client succeeded in authenticating, the client does ... something over the connection. The TCP connection remains "ESTABLISHED" until they disconnect.
4. If the client fails to authenticate (usually after 3 tries), the server drops the connection.

If someone's running a password-guessing attack on you, and you happen to check while they're trying passwords, you'll see an "ESTABLISHED" connection. If they don't delay between attempts (i.e. as soon as one connection attempt fails, reconnect and try again), then you'll pretty much always see an "ESTABLISHED" connection.

On the other hand, if you see the same connection stay up for a while (i.e. the same remote IP and port numbers, rather than continuously changing port numbers), then either someone's gotten in, or they're dawdling for an awfully long time between password guesses. In that case, you should worry.

But if you really want to know what's going on, check the logs! (As Ipor Sircer said in a comment.) Unless an attacker has wiped them, they'll be much more informative than just looking at TCP connections.

Also, since you're under attack (which is automatic, since you have ssh exposed on the internet), make sure your ssh service is [properly locked down](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2271/how-to-harden-an-ssh-server)! Disable root login, limit the users that can log in, make sure to use hard-to-guess passwords, and (if possible) disable passwords in favor of public key authentication.

Comment: cool, I already had no root password and used ssh with rsa keys. I changed the ssh port to something random and unusual as well. What do you mean y disable root login?

Comment: @deltaskelta Add "PermitRootLogin no" to  /etc/ssh/sshd_config. See [the askubuntu question I linked](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2271/how-to-harden-an-ssh-server) for details and more suggestions.

Comment: For this particular case, some emphasis should be placed on some of the lower-down answers for that other question, which deal with _shutting-out such IP addresses_ with firewalls and source IP access rules in the SSH service.

Answer (score 0):

`ESTABLISHED` means the `tcp` socket is in established state i.e. the connection is currently active.

The `tcp` socket tuple is:

```
(my.machine.ip.add:ssh, 116.31.116.48:43270)
```

where the local endpoint is `my.machine.ip.add:ssh`, and remote endpoint being `116.31.116.48:43270`.

So definitely the `ssh` client from `116.31.116.48` is connected to the `ssh` service of your computer.

Comment: ok, that is what I expected, but does that mean that it is authenticated and that they are actually ssh'd `in` my machine. or just that the client has connected to the service (maybe trying to authenticate, or maybe connected)

Comment: @deltaskelta unless there is a bug in `sshd` this means that they have authenticated as the socket becomes `ESTABLISHED` (for a longer time) after the user is authenticated.

Comment: so....It is possible that it is `ESTABLISHED` for a short time even if they have not authenticated, right?

Comment: `ESTABLISHED` just means that the server is talking to the client. It has nothing to do with authentication. An ssh server can wait for input for a very long time unless configured otherwise.

Comment: @KenSharp Yes, thats what i meant too, no? _An ssh server can wait for input for a very long time unless configured otherwise_ seems a bit off putting as unless there is an active request the socket can't be in `ESTABLISHED` state, and the failure drops the connection quickly so the the connection would not be in `ESTABLISHED` state for a longer time unless the user is authenticated.